# What is the necessary speed to travel 1 light-year in 1 year (for the traveler)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation

I am stationary and I want to travel to a destination that is 1 light-year away. This journey needs to last 1 year for me. What is the average speed that my rocket must travel to achieve this?

Consider the stationary reference frame for the distance and the moving reference frame for the time.

Comment: What conceptual questions do you have that would help you solve this homework-like problem?

Comment: *a distance of 1 light-year* Measured by whom?

Comment: @Ghoster, the distance is measured in the stationary reference frame and the time in the moving reference frame.

Comment: Do you assume you will have to accelerate for one half of the trip and then decelerate for the rest half? Or do you assume that desired velocity is reached very quickly and then most of the trip is made with this velocity?

Comment: @JánLalinský wouldn't the average speed be the same in both cases?

Comment: @EduardoM No, because acceleration in the frame of the Earth won't be constant.

Comment: FWIW, in the constant acceleration scenario, the acceleration (as felt by the ship's passengers) is rather high: 30.7 m/s^2 or 3.13 g. The velocity at the midpoint is 0.924c, with Lorentz gamma factor 2.616.

Comment: @JánLalinský, excuse my ignorance on relativity, but what does acceleration have to do with average speed? I mean, in Newtonian physics it's only about distance traveled and time taken. In my example, I'm at rest 1 light-year away from where I was at rest 1 year ago. How does the way I accelerated interfers my average speed from my perspective? Thank you

Comment: @EduardoM Accelerating for half a year and decelerating for the other half with the right acceleration to make 1 light year in 1 year of proper time is a different motion from the uniform motion with the right velocity to do the same. It changes how long the trip takes in Earth's frame, due to continuously changing Lorentz factor in the law of time dilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper time is $$\tau^2=t^2-x^2$$ in units where $c=1$. The distance is $x=1$ and the coordinate time is $t=1/v$. So the proper time is $$1^2=\left(\frac{1}{v}\right)^2 - 1^2$$$$v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$